# Do 3rd Party chrome extensions work in google docs

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

If not, where is the documentation for that?  It seems impossible to find.
Thanks

Comment: It's not clear what exactly is the problem. If by "Google Docs" you mean https://docs.google.com/ then yes, of course extensions can run there.

Comment: OK, thanks, i managed to get them to work but "match_about_blank":true, "all_frames":true were required in content_scripts manifest.  Additionally much functionality doesn't work in docs, where it does on more simple pages.  for example acquiring the selected text on copy events and similar